# a group $G$ whose order has exactly two prime divisors is not simple, Burnside theorem?

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

I have to show that a group $G$ whose order has exactly two prime divisors is not simple. I was thinking to use the Burnside theorem which sais that if $\vert G \vert = p^aq^b$ where $p,q$ are primes and $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ then $G$ is solvable. But I don't know how to continue. Couldn't it be that $\{1\}$ is the only normal subgroup of $G$?

Answer (score 1):

By Burnside, you find $H\lhd G$ with $G/H$ cyclic. If $H=1$, this means $G$ itself is cyclic. The only abelian simple groups are cyclic of prime order.

Comment: Burnside tells us $G$ is solvable, so $G \triangleright G_1\ldots \triangleright G_n=\{1\}$ with $G/G_1$ abelian for example. But why we have a cyclic quotient?

Comment: @roi_saumon: you can refine the series so that the quotients are cyclic.

Comment: I know that for a group $\vert G \vert =p^n$ we can decompose $G\triangleright G_1\triangleright G_2 \triangleright \ldots \triangleright \{1\}$ where $\vert G_1 \vert=p^{n-1}, \vert G_2 \vert = p^{n-2}$ and so on. But here $\vert G \vert = p^aq^b$

Comment: So you know from Burnside that $G$ is soluble, and if it's also simple, then in your series $G_1=1$. Thus $G=G/G_1$ is abelian. In abelian groups all subgroups are normal, so what are the abelian simple groups?

Comment: They are cyclic groups of prime order. So $\vert G \vert = p$ and we have only one and not two prime divisors